# I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community and when running my program it's hanging for some seconds why?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using visual studio 2015 community. Not sure if that's express and if that's what i need.

I see the mouse sign like it's thinking for about 5-10 seconds when running my program. When using visual studio 2013 pro it didn't do it.

I couldn't take a screenshot of it but i see the mouse circle sign thinking for 5-10 seconds before it continue to run my program.

Is there any reason why it's doing it in vs 2015 express ?
Maybe i will try visual studio 2013 express later i just wonder whats wrong with the 2015 express.

If i want to get now visual studio 2013 express should i get this version ?
Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop with Update 4

Comment: half the reason for developers having to get such fast computers is because  of how slow Visual Studios can be

Comment: @ScottSelby As opposed to what? Eclipse? Maybe we should all use vi? [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/378/)

Comment: When you have more plugin/externsions, VS gets slower. That's true. SSD helps here.

Comment: Claiming that Visual Studio is causing lag in the program that **you** have written is somewhat difficult to prove...

Comment: I had this happen to me once. I had turned on fusion logging with "log everything" mode for debugging something and it caused a noticeable slow down.

Comment: Make sure you've got "Just My Code" enabled. Otherwise, VS will load debug symbols for all the microsoft classes too...

Comment: Community edition is not Express edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common issue in Visual studio update 1 RTM. I and other some people debugging winforms app, and found that when we are debugging it's almost hang the computer that we can't even take screenshot.

Did you try update 1 RC (As of now), It have improvement over debugging and it's look to me that this bug has been fixed in update 1 RC.

Comment: Gupta how do i update it if need to ? I did Help > About and under product detail i see: Microsoft Visual Basic 2015 but i didn't find how/where to check for updates.

Comment: You can grab it from here https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx It's too large file to download.